# Pandas: extract top three IDs based on values in a different column from a previous day

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I have a data frame like this:

```
date_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['q','w','e','r','t','y',
           'a','s','d','f','g',
           'z','x',
           'b','n','m','k'],
    'metric': [123,122,45,31,5,2,
               634,372,312,229,110,
               434,334,
               256,156,44,23],
    'date':['2019-11-01','2019-11-01','2019-11-01','2019-11-01','2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', 
             '2019-11-02','2019-11-02','2019-11-02','2019-11-02','2019-11-02',
             '2019-11-04','2019-11-04',
            '2019-11-05','2019-11-05','2019-11-05','2019-11-05']
    })
```

It was sorted by `date` and `metric`. The tricky part is that I have gaps in dates, so I cannot calculate `previous` based on datestamp.
For each date I need to grab top-3 `id`s. If there are fewer `id`s on a previous day, I should use `top_1` instead.
The first date should be filled with NaNs as there is no previous period to look at.
The result should look like this:

```
    id  metric  date        top_1   top_2   top_3
0   q   123     2019-11-01  None    None    None
1   w   122     2019-11-01  None    None    None
2   e   45      2019-11-01  None    None    None
3   r   31      2019-11-01  None    None    None
4   t   5       2019-11-01  None    None    None
5   y   2       2019-11-01  None    None    None
6   a   634     2019-11-02  q       w       e
7   s   372     2019-11-02  q       w       e
8   d   312     2019-11-02  q       w       e
9   f   229     2019-11-02  q       w       e
10  g   110     2019-11-02  q       w       e
11  z   434     2019-11-04  a       s       d
12  x   334     2019-11-04  a       s       d
13  b   256     2019-11-05  z       x       z
14  n   156     2019-11-05  z       x       z
15  m   44      2019-11-05  z       x       z
16  k   23      2019-11-05  z       x       z
```

I will greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have to make some assumptions here. It's not clear what you'd want to do if there was a tie. I also would make a separate dataframe to store the results.

```
# Date should be a datetime
date_test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_test['date'])

# Initialize a place to store results
min_date = date_test['date'].min()
max_date = date_test['date'].max()
solution = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start=min_date,end=max_date,freq='d'))

# Iterate for results
for i in solution.index:
    mask = date_test['date'] == i
    vals = date_test[mask].sort_values('metric',ascending=False)['id'].values[:3]

    # Store results if found
    for j in range(min([3,vals.shape[0]])):
        solution.loc[i,'top_%i'%(j+1)]=vals[j]
```

If you need to offset, you can. Not hard to modify to include the metric in the solution DF.

I'm adding some information based on a comment.

If you want to fill values. You can use `pd.fillna()`. The code below will populate the NA values with the last available date.

```
 solution.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for. If I use offset it will move values for missing dates (2019-11-03 which have all NaNs now) to the next date (2019-11-04). But in the case of a gap in dates, I need values from a previously available date (2019-11-02).

Comment: I updated it based on that note. It should address your problem now.